# Swapping the columns while removing some elements in Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe like this

```
feature feature1
[1,2,3]  0
[4,5,6]  0
0        [6,7,8]   
0        [7,8,9]
```

I want to convert this dataframe like this,

```
feature
[1,2,3]
[4,5,6]
[6,7,8]
[7,8,9]
```

To be precise, look at the attached screenshot

[image: Array represent the feature vectors]

I tried to swap the columns but won't give the correct result.
Please suggest.

Comment: the screenshot and the example does not match , it will be better if you post 5 rows as `df.head(5).to_dict()`

Comment: Yes, I wanted to post by df.head() only but there are total 420 elements in each array and it won't be feasible by that.  @anky

Answer (score 0):

Let's try `where` with `bfill`

```
df.where(df.ne(0)).bfill(1)['feature']
```

Comment: ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all() --- I tried but getting this error.

Answer (score 0):

Try with

```
df['New_feature'] = df.feature.mask(df.feature.eq('0'),df.feature1)
```

Comment: I tried with your solution but it is not giving solution needed, by print(data.New_feature) it just print first column 'feature' elements.

Comment: @AdityaParikh df.feature=df.feature.astype(object), then do above